# How to use arrayformula with a query that groups and sums a certain column in googlesheets

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I am trying to use in `googlesheets` a formula to group data, sum it, and use *arrayformula* function so that it fills a certain column.

Data is as follow:

table 1

| year | quarter | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | T4 | 4 |
| 2022 | T4 | 5 |
| 2023 | T1 | 6 |

I basically want to group by quarter and sum column amount:

table 2

| year | quarter | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | T4 | 9 |
| 2023 | T1 | 6 |

in table 2, col 3, in second row, I have following formula:

```
=query($G$11:I,"select sum(I) where G="&$L11&" and H='"&$M11&"' group by G label sum(I)'' ")
```

this works fine. The issue comes when I try to use arrayformula:

```
=arrayformula(if(L11:L<>"", query($G$11:I,"select sum(I) where G="&$L11&" and H='"&$M11&"' group by G label sum(I)'' "), "no"))
```

I get weird result:

| year | quarter | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | T4 | 9 |
| 2023 | T1 | 9 |
|  |  | no |
|  |  | no |

so the *arrayformula* function works fine, since *col3* is filled with "no" when empty, but I don't understand why for the *2023 T1* row in table 2, the value is **9** instead of **6**. I am using same query.

I've tried *sumifs* etc. but apparently doesn't work that well with *googlesheets*.
I found this:

https://support.google.com/docs/thread/18015573/how-to-use-arrayformula-with-sumifs-function?hl=en

That's why I thought that with a pure query it should work.

Not sure if query is allowed, or my formula can be simplified.

I guess without the arrayformula, I am dragging down, and with the arrayformula it fulfills the column automatically, so there must be the mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARRAYFORMULA can work as an array in many directions, so when it's not that clear it won't work as expected. When you have L11:L and G11:I, and the references inside QUERY that aren't an array, I suppose it takes fine the L column but not the QUERY. You could try adding L11:L and M11:M inside the QUERY.

Or more probably, try with MAP with the ranges and they'll consider them in parallel:

```
=MAP(L11:L,M11:M,LAMBDA(l,m,if(l<>"", query($G$11:I,"select sum(I) where G="&l&" and H='"&m&"' group by G label sum(I)'' "), "no"))))
```

Comment: didn't know about the MAP and LAMBDA functions, they are super useful, thanks!